# I get an error when trying to install the Ruby debugger

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubygems

I am trying to install a ruby debugger for rubymines on an osx mac.

```
Ruby-v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 6
```

When I get this:

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide
while executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3
```

My library and the terminal are accessing different versions. Can someone explain how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using any kind of ruby version manager such as rvm, rbenv, or asdf?

Comment: @JayDorsey I downloaded rbenv and brew. I have spent 2 hours trying to figure this out with no success. my rbenv version is 2.5

Comment: When you run `which ruby` and `ruby --version` what is returned? Also, can you check your bash_profile and make sure rbenv is listed in it? `grep rbenv ~/.bash_profile` should return something. The error you're seeing is a normal permissions error. What's happening is the gem command being run is the default ruby, which tries to write to the directory noted. That directory doesn't have the right permissions on it (and it's best not to mess with it). Better to get your rbenv setup and configured and it will write to the correct location when it's working correctly

Comment: @JayDorsey /usr/bin/ruby  |  ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]  | grep: /Users/user1/.bash_profile: No such file or directory. How do you get the rbenv set up? I have it dowloaded.

Comment: I never recommend rbenv; I always recommend RVM. Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.3.8` (or any given version with the same format, e.g., `rvm install 2.5.3`), then restart your shell and retry your `gem install ...` command.

Comment: @anothermh thank you so much. I was able to successfully download and run the ruby debugger.

Comment: @Lawleyenda there were some other steps in the rbenv install instructions (available via the github repo). I'm glad you were able to get it working with rvm. Your rbenv wasn't configured which is why it was looking in the wrong location to install gems (a location you didn't have permission to install to)